# TYPO3 7.6 load backend user info

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I've added my own scheduler task to the TYPO3 that will, for example, create new page if necessary. The scheduler runs by a special `_cli_scheduler` user and if I create new pages with it, other editors may not see it.

I'm using the `DataHandler` (former `TCE`) to create new pages. The `start()` method accepts an optional parameter - alternative user object that will be used as a creator of the page.

Having `uid` of an editor user, how can I fully instantiate the `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\BackendUserAuthentication` object which then I provide to the `DataHandler::start()`?

I was thinking of using the object manager to get new instance of the mentioned class and just set the `uid` on it, but the `DataHandler` checks some other properties of the `BackendUserAuthentication` object, like permissions, etc.

What is the correct way for getting `BackendUserAuthentication` object will all user data? Is there any factory or a repository I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one was able to help me with this, so I started digging. After some reverse engineering I have found a complete way for loading any backend user as long as you know their ID. I have created a read-only repository with the following method:

```php
public function fetchById($userId)
{
    /** @var BackendUserAuthentication $user */
    $user = $this->objectManager->get(BackendUserAuthentication::class);
    $user->setBeUserByUid($userId);
    $user->resetUC();
    $user->fetchGroupData();
    $user->getFileStorages();
    $user->workspaceInit();
    $user->setDefaultWorkspace();

    return $user;
}
```

It will do the following:

- Load user record from database and store it internally in the `$user` property
- Load the `UC` of the user
- Load user/group permissions
- Initialize file storage
- Initialize workspace

I've dumped user created by this method and compared with the currently logged-in user and it seems that all necessary properties have been set up.

Please let me know if I missed something.